# Laravel Botman Chatbox not displaying

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3, bots, php-5.6

I have followed all the instructions in the below Url.

```
https://botman.io/2.0/installation
```

Then I have run the following command from the project folder.

```
 php artisan serve
```

And then if I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/botman` , I can not see anything happening.

Please help. I am new to Laravel and Botman.

**UPDATE:**

File: `routes/botman.php`

Code:

```
  <?php
use App\Http\Controllers\BotManController;
// Don't use the Facade in here to support the RTM API too :)
$botman = resolve('botman');

$botman->hears('test', function($bot){
    $bot->reply('hello!');
});
$botman->hears('Start conversation', BotManController::class.'@startConversation');
```

The Laravel version is **5.3.31**

Comment: Do you have any error?

Comment: No errors are comming

Comment: Have you try to go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000` first?

Comment: yes I have tried that but it is giving `NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:` error

Comment: Can you include your `routes` file to the question?

Comment: @Jonjie, I have included

Comment: What `laravel` version you're using?  I think there's something wrong with your routes

Comment: @Jonjie, its 5.3.31